FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD not working with Azure devops
I have setup the pipeline using azure devops. It's working fine locally but when running on azure  it says:
Missing password for user saas.tech@sunstone.in, and running in non-interactive shell
what I noticed is azure is looking for FASTLANE_PASSWORD not FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD. (since I am using 2FA I am providing FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD).
Here's my FASTFILE

default_platform(:ios)
xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode_15.3.app")

  desc "Deploy to App Store"
  lane :appstore do
    if is_ci
      setup_ci
    end
    prelane
    match(type: "appstore",app_identifier: "xxxxxx", readonly: is_ci)
    build_app(scheme: "prod" ,export_method: "app-store",clean:true)
    upload_to_app_store(
      app_identifier: "xxxxxxxx",
      skip_metadata: true,
      skip_screenshots: true
    )
  end

and APPFILE
# app_identifier("[[APP_IDENTIFIER]]") # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id("xxxxxxxxxx")
ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] ="xxxxxxxxx"
ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] ="xxxxxxxx"

# For more information about the Appfile, see:
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#appfile


Here's an error

Any help would be appreciated.

Have configured env property to your pipeline task? Which agent was your pipeline running on, MS-hosted or your self-hosted agent? Can you share your pipeline YAML definition to help understand your workflow and let us know which step incurred this error?

Had the error occurred during the App Store Release step? If yes, did you setup the Fastlane Session variable on the Apple App Store service connection? Or did you follow the instructions here to configure authentication for this task?

According to the fastlane docs, You need to provide a pregenerated session via fastlane spaceauth if you have 2-factor authentication enabled and want to use any actions that communicates with App Store Connect.

It's MS-hosted, I think in case 2FA is active, then they recommend using FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD which does not require any OTP. But ok, I will try this way. Thanks!

Anytime. Please let us know if the option to use APIKEY works for you. Thx for your time and efforts.

Hi @anirudhsharma, Hope everything gose well since our last communications. May I know if my suggestion to use APIKEY can resolve your issue in this post? Thank you for your time to update.

When running fastlane commands to deploy app to Apple App Store on local Mac machine, we are prompted to input the app-specific passwords for 2FA. During the continuous deployment on a new agent machine, we are also asked for the security code, which can have the automation tools like Azure Pipelines get stuck.

From the fastlane doc on Continuous Integration,

FASTLANE_SESSION: You need to provide a pregenerated session via fastlane spaceaut if you have 2-factor authentication enabled and want to use any actions that communicates with App Store Connect.

While I would suggest avoiding dealing with the required interaction of using a 2FA enabled account, for example because we want to use spaceship on an automated or CI system that does not support interaction
For this we can use the extension task AppStoreRelease@1 which will install and use fastlane tools during agent job.
Here are the steps for your reference.

Generate a new API key in Apple Store Connect;

Keep note of the Issuer ID and Key ID -> Download the .p8 certificate and convert the key contents to be BASE64 encoded;

I used the PowerShell script running on my Windows machine for encoding;
# Define the path to your .p8 file
$p8FilePath = "C:\Users\Alvin\Downloads\AuthKey_xxxxxx.p8"

# Read the contents of the .p8 file
$p8FileContent = Get-Content -Path $p8FilePath -Raw

# Convert the file contents to a byte array
$p8FileBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($p8FileContent)

# Encode the byte array to a base64 string
$p8FileBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($p8FileBytes)

# Output the base64 string
Write-Output $p8FileBase64


Create a new Apple App Store service connection and input the authentication information;

Deploy the app via the AppStoreRelease@1 pipeline task referencing the new AppleAppStoreSvcCnn;
- task: AppStoreRelease@1
  inputs:
    serviceEndpoint: 'AppleAppStoreSvcCnn'
    releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
    appIdentifier: 'com.mydomain.myapp'
    appType: 'iOS'
    ipaPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.ipa'
    appSpecificId: 'xxxxxx'





Thanks @Alvin for the clarification, will try this way.

Hope it works for you as well and good luck with the work to go. Cheers!

Hi @anirudhsharma, Trust you are doing well. May I know if the suggestion above using API key in the Apple App Store Release task? Thanks for your time and sharing.

Hi @alvin-zhao-msft thanks for reaching out, due to a tight sprint schedule this has been postponed, will be implementing this flow in the coming week Thanks.

Got it and thanks for taking time to share the update. Wish you a productive week.
